# Как найти закономерность получения одной строки из другой?

Tags: алгоритм, строки

Бывают ли какие то способы найти алгоритм, как одна строка получилась из другой? Какая кодировка использовалась?

Например из `E094290CF1FF5F` получилось `3a02fada` ?

Comment: Если об алгоритме преобразования неизвестно вообще ничего, то вряд ли.

Comment: конечно есть. брутфорс называется. берете суперкомпьютер, все кодировки которые только сможете найти и пошло поехало...)))) к следующему тысячелетию может и переберёте. есть правда еще кофейная гуща, но то немного не научный метод :3 p.s. именно кодировки(utf, base64) проще пареной репы, но вот хэш функции... там уже да, весело. веселее некуда. даже в рамках одной хэш функции один и тот же хэш может быть получен из нескольких разных вариантов вводных, а этих функций... достаточно чтоб поседеть и полысеть разом, от представления какой массив данных придется перебрать :3

Comment: Нашел в интернете по кодам: людям нужно подписать прошивку для магнитолы. Слева контрольная сумма прошивки, справа хеш-код, который ей соответствует. В общем это хеш, его можно взломать только если иметь доступ к магнитоле и возможность её отлаживать.

Answer (score 1):

### Коротко: невозможно на практике.

---

Преобразовать строку можно очень разными способами, от [хеш-функций](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A5%D0%B5%D1%88-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F) до [алгоритмов кодирования](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F).

В теории, мы можем перебрать всевозможные алгоритмы, перебрать все значения хешей, но всегда есть вероятность, что строка будет преобразована таким алгоритмом, о котором мы совершенно не знаем (просто что-то придумали из головы).

Поэтому, как уже написали в комментариях: *"Если об алгоритме преобразования неизвестно вообще ничего, то вряд ли."*